# min-height not working for Parent Div

Tags: html, css, css-float

`min-height` is not working for Parent Div after i set `float:left` property to it's child div.

could you help me .

```
<style type="text/css">
*{ margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }

 #wrapperd{
 width : 500px;
 border : 1px solid red;
 min-height:200px;
 }

 #test {
 border:2px solid blue; 
 width:600px; 
 float:left; 
 height:500px;

  }
 </style>
```

HTML code

```
 <div id = "wrapperd"> <!-- Parent Div -->
 <div id = "test"> </div> <!-- Child Div -->
 </div>
```

Demo Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/cFX68/2/

Thanx in Advance :)

Comment: You just need to [clear your floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)!

Comment: One old trick is to add `overflow: hidden;` to the div. Not sure about the downsides tho. http://jsfiddle.net/cFX68/5/

Comment: Like @CherryFlavourPez said — `#wrapperd::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}`

Comment: Your parent div property "min-height" is working fine. As it should.Your floating div, is out of the normal document flow. So your parent div ignores it. Thats why it does not grow accordingly with your floating div,s height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can do.  One is to add a clearing element (with `clear: left` or `clear: both` after the floating element.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/cFX68/3/

The other is to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent div, which has the effect of "pulling" the height of the div down so it surrounds the taller floated div.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/cFX68/4/

Note that this has no effect on the *width* of the child div whatsoever.

Comment: Neither of those are ideal. The first option introduces an unnecessary and non-semantic extra element, and the second is not appropriate as the OP is setting the child width as greater than the parent, so we can assume he *wants* the extra width to be visible. As such, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/3jPSK/) shows the simplest solution. CSS: `#wrapperd:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Classic clear fix issue:
1) set the parent to overflow:hidden; as said above. Only issue is if any content will spill out of the parent box.
2) Another clear fix trick I like to use is: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ which I think is similar to Cherry's comment...